# Saving an MVC View to PDF

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pdf

As the title suggests, I am looking for a way to export a .NET MVC View to a PDF.

My program works like this:

Page 1
Takes in information

Page 2 
Takes this information and heavily styles it with CSS etc

So basically I need to save page 2 after it has been processed and used the information from Page 1's model.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend investigating "HTML to PDF" conversion libraries like [Html2Pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf), [Dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf), or [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). Maybe you can find one to fit your needs.

Comment: I have had a look at these, the problem seems to be the fact that these pages are not static. It works the same way as passing it a link to an email in the web gmail app...

Comment: Ah ok, that method might not work for you then. I was picturing you'd write some code to generate HTML or a DOM object based on your dynamic content and feed that HTML to the conversion library. It's worked for me in PHP, but does take some (sometimes painful) development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render a non-static page to a pdf, you need to render the page to a string, using a ViewModel, and then convert to a pdf:

Firstly, create a method `RenderViewToString` in a static class, that can be referenced in a Controller:

```cs
public static class StringUtilities
{
    public static string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewPath, object model = null, bool partial = false)
    {
        // first find the ViewEngine for this view
        ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = null;
        if (partial)
        {
            viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewPath);
        }
        else
        {
            viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, viewPath, null);
        }

        if (viewEngineResult == null)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("View cannot be found.");
        }

        // get the view and attach the model to view data
        var view = viewEngineResult.View;
        context.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        string result = null;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var ctx = new ViewContext(context, view, context.Controller.ViewData, context.Controller.TempData, sw);
            view.Render(ctx, sw);
            result = sw.ToString();
        }

        return result.Trim();
    }
}
```

Then, in your Controller:

```cs
var viewModel = new YourViewModelName
{
    // Assign ViewModel values
}

// Render the View to a string using the Method defined above
var viewToString = StringUtilities.RenderViewToString(ControllerContext, "~/Views/PathToView/ViewToRender.cshtml", viewModel, true);
```

You then have the view, generated by a ViewModel, as a string that can be converted to a pdf, using one of the libraries out there.

Hope it helps, or at least sets you on the way.

Comment: Thanks for this! Do you perhaps know why it is rendering with special characters like this: "\r \n"?

Comment: These are environment variables that are used to *display* the string with line breaks and carriage returns. To remove these, you can add: viewToString = Regex.Replace(viewToString, @"\t|\n|\r", string.Empty);  OR, if you want to remove spaces as well: viewToString = Regex.Replace(viewToString, @"\t|\n|\r|\s+", string.Empty);

Comment: Question: Does this render the CSS and javascript references in the view? I remember I was using a similar approach, but the generated HTML was malformed because it couldn't find the CSS and javascript files that were referenced.